# Prove or disprove: for all graphs $G = (V, E)$, if $|E| = |V| - 1$ then $G$ is a tree.

Tags: graph-theory

**Relevant Fact**
We know that for all graphs $G = (V, E)$, if $G$ is a tree then $|E| = |V| - 1$.

**Definitions**
A tree is a graph that is connected and has no cycles.
A cycle is like a path, except it starts and ends at the same vertex.

Will soon update with what I have so far. For time being, feel free to add anything.

Would mention that this question is unique in that it does not assume the graph is connected. Thanks everyone!

Comment: this has been asked at least $100$ times before

Comment: Try some small values of $|V|$ and see what happens.

Comment: Hint: Think about disconnected graphs.